# fetch() POST request to Express.js generates empty body {}

Tags: javascript, express, fetch-api, body-parser

**Goal:** send some defined string data from **HTML** in a `fetch()` function e.g. "MY DATA"

---

My code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function fetcher() {
      fetch('/compute',
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: "MY DATA",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        }
      )
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(myJson) {
        console.log(myJson);
      });
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Server.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var app     = express();
var compute = require("./compute");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

//not sure what "extended: false" is for
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/compute', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    var result = compute.myfunction(req.body);
    res.status(200).json(result);
});
```

**Currently:** `console.log(req.body)` logs `{}`

**Desired:** `console.log(req.body)` logs `"MY DATA"`

**NOTES:**

1. I also tried sending body in fetch() as `body: JSON.stringify({"Data": "MY DATA"})` but get the same empty {}
2. I either my fetch() request, or my bodyParser(), is not setup correctly.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add the following line in addition to your current bodyParser app.use() right before:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

This will enable [bodyParser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/master/README.md#bodyparserjsonoptions) to parse content type of `application/json`.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Ahhhh! I had this before, but *after* `app.use(bodyParser.json())`. Switching these around solved it! Thank you.

Comment: The language around 'before' and 'after' here - is a bit confusing! Any clarity on that would be helpful.

Comment: He means to add `app.use(bodyParser.json());` right before the `app.post(...)`

Comment: The 2021 version is to use `app.use(express.json())`

Answer (score 9):

I feel a bit stupid now once I worked out what `bodyParser.urlencoded` (source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions)

> Returns middleware that only parses urlencoded bodies

**Solution**

Changed the `fetch()` request, from:

```
body: "MY DATA",
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
```

to

```
body: JSON.stringify({"Data": "MY DATA"}),
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
```

which solved the problem! Console logged:

> { '{"Data":"MY DATA"}': '' }

Comment: You can keep the application/json content type, just need to add another line of configuration. Try my answer with you original fetch and content type.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky, yes, I prefer your answer since it produces a cleaner response: `{ data: 'MY DATA' }`