# How do I pass additional data from the client-side Stripe Checkout to the server with Fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm trying to setup a subscription service using React on the Frontend, and Node on the Backend. As of now, I've only had success passing the token.id that is generated from this.props.stripe.createToken. The problem I'm having is sending additional info about the customer to my server. How can I pass additional data from the frontend to the server?

I understand that

```
body: JSON.stringify({ token: token.id, email: 'xxx' })
```

helps me submit more data, but how do I extract that info on the server-side? If I console.log(req.body), an empty object is returned

**Solved**
I only had BodyParser processing text, when I really wanted it to be processing JSON. Adding `app.use(bodyParser.json());` fixed it. No more empty req.body!!!

**Frontend**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CardElement, injectStripe } from 'react-stripe-elements';

class CheckoutForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { complete: false };
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
    }

    async submit(ev) {
        let { token } = await this.props.stripe.createToken({ name: 'Bobby' });
        console.log(token);
        let response = await fetch('/charge', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ token: token.id, email: 'xxx' })
        });

        if (response.ok) console.log('Purchase Complete!');
        if (response.ok) this.setState({ complete: true });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.complete) return <h1>Purchase Complete</h1>;

        return (
            <div className="checkout">
                <p>Would you like to complete the purchase?</p>
                <CardElement />
                <button onClick={this.submit}>Send</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default injectStripe(CheckoutForm);
```

**Backend**

```
const app = require('express')();
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_vXWqlxlbpuHTqQgGIUtqOa9c');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/charge', async (req, res) => {
    let newVar = JSON.parse(req.body);
    console.log('new var', newVar);
    try {
        // 1. Create Customer
        stripe.customers.create(
            // where do I pass this info from the frontend?
            {
                email: 'jenny.rosen@example.com',
                source: 'tok_visa'
            },
            function(err, customer) {}
        );

        res.json({ status });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).end();
    }
});

app.listen(9000, () => console.log('Listening on port 9000'));
```

Comment: Where you're passing `body: token.id`, change it to `body: JSON.stringify({token: token.id, email: xxx})`. Possible duplicate of [Fetch: POST json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data)

Comment: @laggingreflex but how do I extract that info on the server-side? If I console.log req.body, it's showing an empty object {}

Comment: Are you using bodyparser? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684372/fetch-post-request-to-express-js-generates-empty-body

Comment: @laggingreflex that solved it! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass an abject to `JSON.stringify` (JSON) to the body attribute of your fetch request.

```
...
let response = await fetch('/charge', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
        token: '',
        name: '',
        userid: 123,
    }),
})
...
```

You have to update the header `Content-Type` to pass `application/json`.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I extract that info on the server-side? If I console.log req.body, it's showing an empty object {}

Comment: You should use `JSON.parse(req.body)`, that would give an object of data you have posted. @WMG

Comment: Please read my answer again, You need to update the header to the `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}` @WMG

Comment: I've adjusted my code above, but when I try to assign the result to a var, I'm getting an error. Let me know what you think